# Exception by domain - Email and Case workflow

Tags: workflow, case, case-object, email2case

We have email-to-case. Every customer email into a case generates a case comment, which is then mailed back to the customer using workflow rules as confirmation of the update.

One customer doesn't want a notification confirming the information they have just sent, so I am trying to make an exception for that customer in the workflow.

At the moment I have a workflow on the email object to pick up incoming mail from this customer's domain. When an incoming mail from this customer is detected, a date/time field (MailDateTime__c) is updated on the case object with the value now(), so each subsequent mail from this customer produces a different value and the field is changed.

I have tried to include this exception in the existing workflow like this:

```
NOT(ISCHANGED(MailDateTime__c))
```

So an email is NOT sent when the datetime field is updated, but it isn't working and a notification is sent.

Here is the complete rule criteria:

```
AND(($RecordType.Name = 'FPI'),
ISCHANGED(Last_Public_Comment__c),
(Initial_Mail_Despatched__c = TRUE),
NOT(ISCHANGED(MailDateTime__c)),
NOT (ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed")))
```

Any help gratefully accepted...

Comment: If only one customer don't want, Then may be you need to create a new field on case or contact(depending on whether he dosn't want for this case or all the cases for this customer) lie opt-out confirmation and then use that field in the email alert. I don't think you can just exclude one customer/case without including their id in your existing WF.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Veera G. The customer has many accounts and contacts, so the maintenance of a flag on account or contact would be a problem. Also, the customer needs to receive case updates from our users, so I can't block all notifications, only those generated by incoming mail from the customer. This is why I've chosen to identify the customers domain on incoming emails: it's the only way to exclude only their comments from the notification workflow.

Comment: Will you not be able to use "incoming" checkbox from emailmessage object.

Comment: The problem with a checkbox is it only has two states, so when it's been 'switched on' it will remain on and the workflow rule will fail because it wont 'be changed' by subsequent incoming emails. The benefit of a datetime field using formula now() is every incoming mail will generate a new value and change the field, which should suppress the workflow